# AWS Elastic Beanstalk - switching environment variables between environments

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using Elastic Beanstalk's `aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment` namespace to configure my environment with env vars. How can I set different values for different environments (e.g. development versus production)?

#### Development:

```yaml
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    REDIS_HOST: localhost
```

#### Production:

```yaml
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    REDIS_HOST: prod.redis.server.com
```

Comment: [AWS suggests storing the DB password in an S3 file](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.RDS.html?icmpid=docs_elasticbeanstalk_console#rds-external-credentials). Perhaps you could follow similar pattern for different env with each env getting config from a different S3 file.

Answer (score 4):

The AWS CLI has a convenient way of doing this for you as the `update-environment` command allows you to set env vars from a specially formatted json file. Create a separate json file for each environment you will be deploying to.

Example json file named `deploy-dev.json`:

```
[
  {
    "Namespace": "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment",
    "OptionName": "NODE_ENV",
    "Value": "dev"
  },
  {
    "Namespace": "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment",
    "OptionName": "LOG_LEVEL",
    "Value": "silly"
  }
]
```

Deploy app and then update env vars:

```
aws elasticbeanstalk create-application-version --application-name "$EB_APP_NAME" --version-label "$EB_VERSION"
aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment --environment-name "$EB_ENV_NAME" --version-label "$EB_VERSION" --option-settings file://.ebextensions/deploy-dev.json
```

Answer (score 2):

How it's changed depends on your deployment method.

One option you can use is to set a bogus value in your `.config` file:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    REDIS_HOST: change me
```

Then, after deployment, modify the variable either using the AWS Management Console or using the EB CLI:

```
eb setenv REDIS_HOST=prod.redis.server.com
```

If you are using CloudFormation to deploy your EB application, you can feed the value as part of the `OptionSettings` field in your CloudFormation template:

```
    "EBConfigurationTemplate" : {
        "Type" : "AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ConfigurationTemplate",
        "Properties" : {
            "ApplicationName" : {
                "Ref" : "EBApplication"
            },
            "Description"     : "Configuration Template",
            "OptionSettings"  : [
                {
                    "Namespace" : "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment",
                    "OptionName" : "REDIS_HOST",
                    "Value"      : {
                        "Ref" : "RedisHostInputParameter"
                    }
                },
            ]
```

There are probably other methods too, but they will depend on the method of deployment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm looking for an automated way of doing this, so your option 1 won't work for my needs. I'm not using CloudFormation but I might have to look into deploying with it.

Comment: What is your current automated deployment method?

Comment: I am using Elastic Beanstalk with the env var .config file. This auto generates these env vars during deployment. I currently only have a development env so when creating a prod env I just need to switch these values

Comment: Yes, but how do you **deploy** your app bundle to EB? Do you use the EB CLI? AWS Management Console? Other?

Comment: Yes, through the EB CLI. I guess we could make a script to perform the `setenv`

Comment: Yes, do both. Deploy, then set the variable with `eb setenv`. Many times, deployments to production are a multi-stage process that requires scripting.

Comment: I was assuming that Elastic Beanstalk would have support for this, so unless somebody else has a solution then I will use scripting. Thanks!